# Изменить вывод заголовка столбца

Tags: java, swing, jtable, таблицы

Есть JTable, пробегаюсь по столбцам и меняю размеры (min, max, pref).

При установке размера, если название столбца больше чем установленное значение, то в название столбца обрезается и добавляется `"..."`.

Как избавится от этих точек (хочу пустоту)?

Если через headerRender то какой метод?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо воспользоваться методом `JTableHeader.setDefaultRenderer` и классом `JTextField` для вывода заголовков колонок:

```
JTable table = new JTable(<Ваши аргументы>);

table.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table,
        Object value,
        boolean isSelected,
        boolean hasFocus,
        int row,
        int column) {
            JTextField field = new JTextField();
            field.setText(value? value.toString(): "");
            return field;
        }
    });
```